# Error: Object variable or with block code not set

Tags: excel, vba, macos

The code is actually looking for a formula from a range in another workbook

The following code gives me error object code : on line 6

```
With ws1
    i = 6
    Do Until .Cells(i, 3) = ""
        If .Cells(i, 3).Value <> "NA" Then
                Set rngStatus = rngLookup.Find(.Cells(i, 3).Value)
                vCurrYear = rngStatus.EntireRow.Cells(1, 12).Formula
                vPrevYear = rngStatus.EntireRow.Cells(1, 11).Formula
            If Not IsError(v) Then .Cells(i, 5) = vCurrYear And .Cells(i, 4) = vPrevYear
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End With
```

Comment: You can't use `And` this way `If Not IsError(v) Then .Cells(i, 5) = vCurrYear And .Cells(i, 4) = vPrevYear`  They need to be on separate lines with an `End If`

Comment: Thank for your comment! The error is in line 6: 'vCurrYear = rngStatus.EntireRow.Cells(1, 12).Formula'

Comment: Then `.Cells(i, 3).Value` is not found in `rngLookup` and `rngStatus` is Nothing.

Comment: The `.Cells(i, 3).Value` was found and `rngStatus` wasn't empty

Comment: It gives me *Run time error 91: Object variable or with block variable not set* for code `vCurrYear = rngStatus.EntireRow.Cells(1, 12).Formula`

Comment: Which is what I would expect if `rngStatus` is Nothing.

Comment: Test it, add this line after the find line: `If rngStatus is nothing then msgbox .Cells(i, 3).Value & " Not Found"`

Comment: What is rngLookup pointing too?  You haven't supplied that

Comment: Seems to me you should be doing something like this...
                vCurrYear = rngStatus.Value
                vPrevYear = rngStatus.Offset(-1, 0).Value